# Excel IF function with hours

Tags: microsoft-excel

I'm having trouble with the IF function in Excel.

I have a cell, set as "date/hour" with the format "24:00" and I want this computation (let say cell A5):

```
if A5 < 0:30, then A5 == 0:30, else A2-A1
```

Basically: if A5 is less than half an hour, it must show half an hour, otherwise the difference.
I did that like:

```
=IF(A5<0:30;"0:30";A2-A1)
```

but is not working. What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: (1) Please don’t post questions that say “it is not working”.  ***Something*** is happening.  Error message?  Wrong value?  Your computer explodes?  Always say *what **is** happening.*  (2) You maybe seem to have the common misconception that a cell can *contain* one value and *display* a different one.  OK, this is not totally impossible, but it’s not a road you want to go down if you’re a beginner.  Don’t try to have ```A5``` display `0:30` if `A5` contains a value less than `0:30`.  If you want to put this formula in `A6`, or anywhere else (other than `A1`, `A2` or `A5`), that’s fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use strings such as `"00:30"` directly in arithmetic operations such as `<` and `-` just like you cannot use any string with arithmetic operations. Instead of using strings, it is generally preferable to store them as the numbers that Excel uses for dates and times (see [https://excel.tips.net/T002176_How_Excel_Stores_Dates_and_Times.html#:~:text=Internally%2C%20Excel%20stores%20a%20date%20or%20time%20as,decimal%20point%29%20represents%20the%20time%20for%20that%20date](https://excel.tips.net/T002176_How_Excel_Stores_Dates_and_Times.html#:%7E:text=Internally%2C%20Excel%20stores%20a%20date%20or%20time%20as,decimal%20point%29%20represents%20the%20time%20for%20that%20date). for more details).

Formatting cells using the `Time` option will display them with a format of `hh:mm:ss`. Formatting cells such as `A1`,`A2` and `A5` with the `Time` format (or a `Custom` format such as `hh:mm` will allow you to enter time values using hours and minutes but Excel will actually store them as internal date/time numbers (you can temporarily change the cell formats to `General` to see what these numbers are).

If you do this then changing you your formula to

`=IF(A5<TIME(0,30,0),TIME(0,30,0),A2-A1)`

will do what you want. The `TIME` function takes three arguments of hour, minute and seconds so `TIME(0,30,0)` is the same as the time of 00:30:00 (ie 1/48 or 0.0208333333333333 when expressed as a number).

Whilst Hannu's mention of the `TEXT` function is correct and will convert a number to a an `hh:mm` representation of that number, the resulting value is a string and so (i) cannot be used in arithmetic operations and (ii) does not directly preserve the underlying numeric value. However, the `VALUE` function can be used to retrieve the numeric value from the string (for example `=VALUE("00:30")` delivers the number   0.0208333333333333), so the underlying numeric value is preserved but indirectly.

Excel's approach to dates and times and the associated functions is worth getting to know. It will make it much easier to understand and create arithmetic operations on dates and times if you do.

Comment: I agree that it’s very important to understand how Excel handles and stores dates and times — namely, it handles them as numbers, not as strings. But your statement “You cannot use strings such as `"00:30"` directly in arithmetic operations …” goes too far. The OP *could* use `=IF(A5<("0:30"+0), "0:30"+0, A2-A1)` if they wanted to.

Comment: I agree. But this only happens because the strings are coerced to act as the underlying numbers. In general, reliance on this sort of coercion is a pretty poor practice IMHO and, for the level of knowledge displayed by the OP, I think it preferable that the subtlety of "00:30" and "00:30"+0 being different and the reasons for this are probably best left until a sound base of knowledge has been developed. Just my opinion as a former practitioner, mentor, manager and teacher.

Answer (score 1):

Note that all time and date values are stored as offsets from a base date.

`=TEXT(A5;"HH:MM")` will display A5 contents as `00:30`
*(the result can be used in that format in a formula!)*
but the actual value is `0.020833333333333` representing the offset of 30 minutes from the base date.

Every 24 hours adds 1.0 to the value, and the 30 minute value above used as in this formula `=1/(0.020833333333333/30/60)` - shows a result of `86400`
... the number of seconds per 24 hours (=24x60x60).

Enter a `0` in a cell and format it as a date (full with year and all) and you will se the base date; which may differ from one spreadsheet (software!) to next, also depending on file format.

Answer (score 0):

Not need for an `iF` to show `30:00` if the time is less than half an hour, you can use:

```
=MAX(1/48,A5)
```

For Excel, `1` is a full day, 1/2 hour is (1/24)/2 or 1/48)

As Hannu mentions, you do need to format the cell as Time

Comment: Yeah, but the OP isn’t trying to do `=IF(A5<0:30;"0:30";A5)`; they’re trying to do `=IF(` `A5<0:30;` `"0:30";` *`something completely different`* `)`.